# Bash: How can i split a string which has no delimiter?

Tags: bash

I have a string `36K    total,TOO_MANY_NEWLINE_IN_TEXT_tABLE`. From this string i need only `36`.

is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean? Is your string static and you know where the position of "36" is? Or you want any number in your dynamic string?

Comment: Or you just want firs 2 characters in any string?

Comment: i need first 2 characters of a sting

Comment: @RajasekarKaliyamoorthi It's called a *string*, not *sting*.

Comment: `echo '36K total,TOO_MANY_NEWLINE_IN_TEXT_tABLE' | sed 's/[^0-9].*//'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try this:

```
echo "36K    total,TOO_MANY_NEWLINE_IN_TEXT_tABLE" | grep -oEi '([0-9])+'
```

Comment: Why use the `-i` flag?

Comment: @melpomene man grep. I guess you don't need to ignore case for numbers. I thought it would be nice to include -i, in case, he uses it to capture values other integers.

Answer (score 2):

As described in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion, you can write

```
echo "${foo:0:2}"
```

to output the first two characters of a variable `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the leading number (of variable length) from a string in pure `bash` (without any external tools), you can use the [`=~` operator](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression#regular_expression_matching) (extended regex match) inside the [conditional expression `[[ .. ]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

```
$ line='36K    total,TOO_MANY_NEWLINE_IN_TEXT_tABLE'
$ [[ $line =~ [0-9]* ]] && echo "$BASH_REMATCH"
36
```

Answer (score 0):

You *have* a delimiter; the letter `K` separates the first desired substring, `36`, from the rest of the string.

```
$ str="36K    total,TOO_MANY_NEWLINE_IN_TEXT_tABLE"
$ IFS=K read num rest <<< "$str"
$ echo "$num"
36
```